# Java Random генерация случайных слов

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Добрый день! Занимаюсь по книге Эккеля и столкнулся с ниже представленным примером. Не могу понять, почему на выводе программа всегда выдает один и тот же результат? Если я правильно понял, то каждый раз символы должны генерироваться случайно. Заранее спасибо!

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomWords implements Readable {
    private static Random rand = new Random(47);
    private static final char[] capitals =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    private static final char[] lowers =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    private static final char[] vowels =
            "aeiou".toCharArray();
    private int count;
    public RandomWords(int count) { this.count = count; }
    public int read(CharBuffer cb) {
        if(count-- == 0)
            return -1;
        cb.append(capitals[rand.nextInt(capitals.length)]);
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            cb.append(capitals[rand.nextInt(vowels.length)]);
            cb.append(capitals[rand.nextInt(lowers.length)]);
        }
        cb.append(" ");
        return 10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new RandomWords(10));
        while(s.hasNext())
            System.out.println(s.next());
    }
}

/* Output :
YAZBREYAC
FDWBNECDR
GDEAZCMDM
RAEEUACCO
NEOADBSCW
HAGBACKEX
REQCCCBEI
NEMASBTCH
KEUEUDZDG
WAQCZBYDY */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина здесь

```
private static Random rand = new Random(47);
```

На правой странице конструктор использует константное семя `47`, что значит, что он всегда будет генерировать ту же самую последовательность случайных чисел.

Когда вы используете другое число вместо `47`, вы получите другую последовательность, но опять всегда ту же самую.

Чтобы получить всегда новую и новую последовательность, нужно всегда задать новое семя - стандартный способ, как это сделать, есть использовать текущие бремя, например

```
private static Random rand = new Random(new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: лучше уж так: `new Random()` в качестве `seed` там будет выступать `System.nanoTime() + что то там`

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, вы прав. Спасибо.